# read output from subprocess.Popen in python

Tags: python, subprocess, psexec

I am trying to run the following subprocess.Popen() command in python 2.6

```
output = subprocess.Popen("psexec -accepteula \\machineName -u username -p password cmd.exe /C fsutil fsinfo drives", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
print(output.communicate())
```

But I get the following result with output.communicate()

```
('\r\n', '\r\nPsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely\r\nCopyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich\r\nSysinternals - www.sysinternals.com\r\n\r\nConnecting to machineNameHere...\r\r\rStarting PSEXESVC service on machineNameHere...\r\r\rConnecting with PsExec service on machineNameHere...\r\r\rStarting cmd.exe on machineNameHere...\r\r\r\r\ncmd.exe exited on machineNameHere with error code 0.\r\n')
```

When I run the same psexec command from cmd line in windows, I get the correct output.

```
PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

**Drives: A:\ C:\ D:\**
cmd.exe exited on machineNameHere with error code 0.
```

I am looking for the output **Drives: A:\ C:\ D:** even while running the psexec command using subprocess.Popen(). Any way I can do it?

---

Now I narrowed down the issue by running different commands like dir and echo "test". The issue seems to be that Popen is reading only first line into stdout  and not the complete output. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Read from the process stdout directly.

Comment: Perhaps the backslashes are being interpreted differently between the two environments?  Try using a raw string for the Popen command.

Comment: PsExec will not relay client output to you. It is better to use OpenSSH to launch commands remotely, although it is somewhat a pain to install on Windows. You can also roll your own JSON server.

Comment: @RishavKundu - do you suggest using **output.stdout.readlines()** ?

Answer (score 1):

(expanding on John Gordon's comment on the question)

---

you are trying to run this command through a shell:
`"psexec -accepteula \\machineName -u username -p password cmd.exe /C fsutil fsinfo drives"`

notice that you have double backslashes within the command (`\\machineName`).  The backslash happens to be an escape character in string literals (used to escape characters that otherwise have a special meaning).  Therefore, `\\machineName` is getting translated to `\machineName` before it is passed to the spawned process.

here are 2 ways to handle this:

1) prepend an escape character (another backslash) before each backslash:
`"psexec -accepteula \\\\machineName"`

2) add an 'r' before the string literal, which makes it a a raw string, and will not interpret the backlsashes as escape chars:
`r"psexec -accepteula \\machineName"`

---

Here is an example in the python interpreter that should make it clear.  Notice the output that gets printed:

```
>>> print("\\machineName")
\machineName
>>> print("\\\\machineName")
\\machineName
>>> print(r"\\machineName")
\\machineName
```

Comment: Hi Corey, I see that the problem here is not with backslash because I am able to run the command on remote machine. To check if it actually works, I changed the command that needs to run on remote machine to just echo some thing and I get back the output. It is only when I try to run the command **cmd.exe /C fsutil fsinfo drives** that the output is not captured by subprocess.